# return Array To Functions with AJAX

Tags: jquery

i just want to ask if how to return or how to call the returned arrays to the function..

this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(askServer());   

function askServer()
{
 var strUrl = "functions.php";
 var strReturn = new Array();

 jQuery.ajax({
  url:strUrl, success:function(html){strReturn = html;}, async:false
 });

 return strReturn;
}
});
```

and this is from my functions.php..

```
<?php
$dirArray = Array('data_1','data_2','data_3');
echo $dirArray;
?>
```

my problem is it will alert the word "Array"/...

can it be done like this?

```
alert(askServer()[0]);
```

to alert "data_1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several flaws here:

First you cannot assign `strReturn` this way because `return strReturn;` will be executed before the Ajax is finished (oh I see you have `async: false` but that is always a bad idea).

Second, you cannot just send an PHP array this way. It shows `Array` because this is what happens if you convert an array to a string.

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php) to transform the array to [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

```
<?php
$dirArray = Array('data_1','data_2','data_3');
echo json_encode($dirArray); // will now be '["data_1", "data_2","data_3"]'
?>
```

and on the client side do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

askServer(function(data){
    alert(data[0])
});   

function askServer(callback)
{
    var strUrl = "functions.php";

    jQuery.ajax({
       url:strUrl, 
       success:callback, 
       dataType: "json" 
    });

}
});
```

This is what happens: You pass a callback function to `askServer` that should be executed once the Ajax request is complete. You specify that the response will be a JSON string so jQuery automatically transforms this into an Object/Array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you just can't echo Array.

There are three (probably even more:]) possibilites to interchange arrays (as logical structures) between PHP and JS:

1., explode on PHP side, implode JS routine in your page

explode takes values of array and glues them together with your string (i.e. 'GLUE'):

```
array('str1','str2') => 'str1GLUEstr2' with
implode('GLUE', $array);
```

2., JSON: read at http://www.json.org
3., XML: read at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/10/10/jquery-and-xml.html